# How to separate rows in CSV file into two separate files where IDs match certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new to Python and currently trying to find the most efficient way to remove rows from my CSV file using Pandas that match certain condition.

CSV file1 structure:

```
 id      product   userCount    warehouse      date
 1       Guitar       0           D-12      2020-03-10
 2       Drums        1           F-1       2020-03-10
 3       Piano        1           E-9       2020-03-10
 1       Guitar       0           D-12      2020-03-09
 2       Drums       12           F-1       2020-03-09
 3       Piano        0           E-9       2020-03-09
 1       Guitar       0           D-12      2020-03-08
 2       Drums       10           F-1       2020-03-08
 3       Piano        0           E-9       2020-03-08
 ...
```

My goal (condition): Separate records for specific IDs that have 0 userCount in all rows (result1) from rest of the rows that have at least 1 or more in userCount in all rows (result2).

result1:

```
 id      product   userCount    warehouse      date
 1       Guitar       0           D-12      2020-03-10
 1       Guitar       0           D-12      2020-03-09
 1       Guitar       0           D-12      2020-03-08
 ...
```

result2:

```
 id      product   userCount    warehouse      date
 2       Drums        1           F-1       2020-03-10
 3       Piano        1           E-9       2020-03-10
 2       Drums       12           F-1       2020-03-09
 3       Piano        0           E-9       2020-03-09
 2       Drums       10           F-1       2020-03-08
 3       Piano        0           E-9       2020-03-08
 ...
```

As desired output I need two separate files. Output1.csv that contains rows with result1 and Output2.csv that contains rows with result2.

My code so far is as below. However, somehow it moves some rows with only 0 values into Output2.csv that should not have those at all. Can someone help?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

#Read input file
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/input.csv')

#separate IDs that are =0 and >0 into separate files
mask = df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['userCount'] != 0, 'id'])
ids1 = df.loc[~mask, 'id'].unique()
ids2 = df.loc[mask, 'id'].unique()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids1, 'userCount':0})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids2, 'userCount':'>0'})

df1.to_csv('path/to/my/temp/file/zeroFlagID.csv')
df2.to_csv('path/to/my/temp/file/NonZeroFlagID.csv')

fields=['id','product','userCount','warehouse','date']

#read IDs from temp file and merge with relevant columns from input file
df3 = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/temp/file/zeroFlagID.csv', sep = ',')
df4 = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/input.csv', sep = ',', usecols=fields)

df5 = df3.merge(df4, on="id")

df5.to_csv('path/to/my/output1.csv', index = False)

fields2=['id','product','userCount','warehouse','date']

#read IDs from temp file and merge with relevant columns from input file
df6 = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/temp/file/NonZeroFlagID.csv', sep = ',')
df7 = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/input.csv', sep = ',', usecols=fields2)


df8 = df6.merge(df7, on="id")

df8.to_csv('path/to/my/output2.csv', index = False)

#remove temp files
os.remove('path/to/my/temp/file/NonZeroFlagID.csv')
os.remove('path/to/my/temp/file/zeroFlagID.csv')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Output.csv', sep=',')

prod_cnt = df.groupby('product').userCount.sum()

df[df['product'].isin(prod_cnt[prod_cnt == 0].index)].to_csv('Output1.csv')
df[df['product'].isin(prod_cnt[prod_cnt != 0].index)].to_csv('Output2.csv')
```

Screenshot of input file:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rene, this is separating my file with 0 and non 0 rows into two files. I'm looking for a solution which would recognize if any of the IDs in my input file have rows for all dates =0 (then move rows for those IDs to output1.csv) and if any of the IDs in my input file have at least one row for any date greater than 0 (then move rows for all dates including 0 for that ID into output2.csv). Not sure if I explain it right, let me know if you need some more details. In results2 you can see for example 'Piano' has userCount for one date =1 for two other dates = 0. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I have just one more question. How do I pass all the rows from my input.csv into 's' variable? as I have hundreds of them and each day a new row for  a new date is added in this file. Can I somehow link s variable to my input.csv file directly? From above it seems that I would have to add all rows manually, but I might be wrong as Im only a beginner

Comment: You can use `df = pd.read_csv('Output.csv', sep=',')` for that.

Comment: Would it be possible to include in the above answer? I'm struggling and getting this error: `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame` when trying `df = pandas.read_fwf(io.StringIO(df))`. Not sure how to display all my rows from input.csv correctly and pass it as  `df = pandas.read_fwf(io.StringIO(s))`. Sorry for so many questions and thank you!

Comment: Just to make sure, your file `Output.csv` is comma separated, right?

Comment: I guess you meant input file? then yes, correct. It's comma separated.

Comment: I updated my answer. I trust you will upvote and accept my answer :-)